# Fully static libcurl build

Tags: linux, curl, static, hyperlink, compilation

I am building a program (on linux) which relies on libcurl. I'd prefer that it could be distributed and run without needing any external dependencies. libcurl seems to have quite a few of these... hence, I would like to know if there is any way to statically compile libcurl so as to include all of its dependencies?

Or, do any pre-built versions of it already exist?

Comment: I think the main reason people prefer to build from source is because they then know (assuming the compiler has no backdoor, which would be very complex to implement anyway) that they get what the source says and not something else. This is also why you have signed source packages, i.e. the "(gpg)" link after the respective download link on the curl website ;) ... basically you really don't want to do that. Especially given how trivial it is on Linux to build something (unlike Windows where often no tool chain is installed for starters).